# I want to run an old GNOME app

Tags: 20.04, gnome, gvfs, gthumb

I know that what I want to do is a bit unusual, but I have a need to run a quite old version of gThumb (2.10.11, coming from Ubuntu 10.04) on Ubuntu 20.04.

(Someone asked me in the comments why, so here's the explanation: that old version has a very good slideshow mode, which provides several features that the current version of gThumb present in Ubuntu 20.04 does **not** provide. Among them are: 1) option "fit to screen only for larger images" works in slideshow mode; 2) GIF animations are played in slideshow mode; 3) the shortcut key "I" - display information about the current image - works in slideshow mode. All this does NOT work in current gThumb).

Until now, I managed to collect all the old libraries needed to run this app into a single directory (so all dependencies are satisfied), the app starts and the GUI appears (screenshot below). However, the app is unable to communicate with current GNOME VFS daemon and therefore does not load the folder contents, so it is in fact unusable. The following error message appears in the terminal:

```
(gthumb:13485): libgnomevfs-WARNING **: 13:34:54.800: Failed to activate daemon: The name org.gnome.GnomeVFS.Daemon was not provided by any .service files
```

[image]

There is definitely some incompatibility between the old and new GNOME VFS daemon and the app cannot communicate with it. Is there any way to fix this and make the app run on my system - for example, by making the app don't use VFS but just directly read from disk instead? (except of having to rebuild the app myself, as I don't see this feasible)

As the issue is related to VFS, I tried to replace the `libgnomevfs-2.so.0` library that I copied from Ubuntu 10.04 with the newest one I could find, that is from Ubuntu 18.04 (there is no `libgnomevfs-2.so.0` library available for 20.04). However, the effect is the same. So the change to VFS must have occurred between 18.04 and 20.04.

Comment: Bad idea.  You will break your system because the dependencies are not going to work out.  I suggest doing this in a VM container so that it won't damage your system installation.  If you are using an EOL version of Ubuntu in the container, make sure that networking is disabled in the VM.

Comment: This also seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  Why do you think you need a ten year old image viewer?  What is the *actual* problem that you are experiencing?

Comment: Do you realize that normal modern precompiled deb-package exists at https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gthumb ? What is your final idea with running software from Ubuntu Lucid Lynx (2010 year)?

Comment: @Nmath I used a lot the gThumb slideshow option in 10.04 and there are several features that current gThumb does **not** provide in slideshow mode (an option "fit to screen only for larger images" can be used; GIF animations are played in slideshow mode; the "I" key works); shortly speaking, the current version of gThumb is far worse than the old one. Therefore I want to run the old one.

Comment: @Nmath Also, as I already wrote, I was able to fulfill the dependencies, the application runs and does not complain about any missing library (I just put all the required libraries into the same dir as the `gthumb` binary and run it with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set to that directory). It "only" can't communicate with the recent GNOME backend. I am interested if this can be soved somehow.

Comment: GNOME devs have been removing a lot of useful features lately. Try Eye of MATE. `sudo apt install eom-common`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. The problem was that in addition to regular GNOME VFS daemon (`/usr/libexec/gvfsd`, or `/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd` in older versions of Ubuntu), there was another daemon used by gThumb up to Ubuntu 18.04 - `/usr/lib/gnome-vfs-2.0/gnome-vfs-daemon`. This daemon is not present anymore in Ubuntu 20.04, so the old gThumb is not able to access files/folders on disk. It was needed to copy the daemon to Ubuntu 20.04, so that the application can use it.

The full solution to make the application run is as follows (this is long and probably nobody except me is interested in this, but as I solved the problem I post an answer, maybe somebody in the future can use it :)):

(BTW. I suppose that all this can be made into an AppImage package, if I only knew how to do it :))

1. create a directory for the old gThumb application, for example `/opt/gthumb_old`.
2. from working installation of 64-bit Ubuntu 10.04, copy the following files to `/opt/gthumb_old` (I had such an installation available; in case it isn't available, you need to identify packages containing these files, download them and extract the files, which requires more work):

```
/usr/bin/gthumb
/usr/lib/gthumb/libgthumb.so
/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so
/usr/lib/glade/2.0/libbonobo.so
/usr/lib/glade/2.0/libcanvas.so
/usr/lib/glade/2.0/libgnome.so
/usr/lib/gnome-vfs-2.0/gnome-vfs-daemon
/usr/lib/libart_lgpl_2.so.2
/usr/lib/libaudiofile.so.0
/usr/lib/libbonobo-2.so.0
/usr/lib/libbonobo-activation.so.4
/usr/lib/libbonoboui-2.so.0
/usr/lib/libcanberra-gtk.so.0
/usr/lib/libcanberra.so.0
/usr/lib/libesd.so.0
/usr/lib/libfam.so.0
/lib/libgcrypt.so.11
/usr/lib/libglade-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/libgnome-2.so.0
/usr/lib/libgnomecanvas-2.so.0
/usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0
/usr/lib/libgnomeui-2.so.0
/usr/lib/libgnomevfs-2.so.0
/usr/lib/libgnutls.so.26
/usr/lib/libhal-storage.so.1
/usr/lib/libhal.so.1
/usr/lib/libiptcdata.so.0
/usr/lib/libopenrawgnome.so.1
/usr/lib/libopenraw.so.1
/usr/lib/libORBit-2.so.0
/usr/lib/libORBitCosNaming-2.so.0
/lib/libpng12.so.0
/usr/lib/libtasn1.so.3
/usr/lib/libtiff.so.4
```

The above `/usr/lib/*.so.*` or `/lib/*.so.*` files are symlinks to other files, so you have of course to copy the file the link points to, but the target name should be the one of the link. (If you use `cp` or `scp` to copy the above names, you don't have to worry about this, as this happens automatically.)

You need also to **symlink** `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8` to `libjpeg.so.62` in `/opt/gthumb_old`. The application expects to link to `libjpeg.so.62` but the original `libjpeg.so.62` library copied from Ubuntu 10.04 does not work properly and JPEG files are not displayed; so we will use the present system library instead.

3. create a directory `/opt/gthumb_old/glade` and copy contents of `/usr/share/gthumb/glade` from Ubuntu 10.04 installation to this directory.
4. create a directory `/opt/gthumb_old/modules` and copy contents of `/usr/lib/gthumb/modules` from Ubuntu 10.04 installation to this directory.
5. create a directory `/opt/gthumb_old/vfs_modules` and copy contents of `/usr/lib/gnome-vfs-2.0/modules` from Ubuntu 10.04 installation to this directory.
6. create a directory `/opt/gthumb_old/modules_conf` and copy contents of `/etc/gnome-vfs-2.0/modules` from Ubuntu 10.04 installation to this directory.
7. create a subdirectory `.gtk-2.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/engines` in your `/home/username` directory and copy the file `/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/engines/libmurrine.so` from Ubuntu 10.04 to this directory. This is needed for menus and other UI gadgets to be displayed correctly (the application will work without this file, but the UI will be distorted a bit). If you don't have Adobe Reader 9 installed (the last available version for Linux), you can skip the intermediate `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` subdirectory and put the file just in `.gtk-2.0/engines`. But if you have Adobe Reader installed (like I do), it needs a 32-bit version of the file `libmurrine.so`, which should be located in `.gtk-2.0/i686-pc-linux-gnu/engines`, therefore it is better to use the "longer" version.
8. create a symlink `/usr/share/gthumb/glade` pointing to `/opt/gthumb_old/glade`.
9. create a symlink `/usr/lib/gthumb/modules` pointing to `/opt/gthumb_old/modules` (the directory `/usr/lib/gthumb` does not exist in standard installation of Ubuntu 20.04, so you have to create it first)
10. create a symlink `/usr/lib/gnome-vfs-2.0/modules` pointing to `/opt/gthumb_old/vfs_modules` (the directory `/usr/lib/gnome-vfs-2.0` does not exist in standard installation of Ubuntu 20.04, so you have to create it first)
11. create a symlink `/etc/gnome-vfs-2.0/modules` pointing to `/opt/gthumb_old/modules_conf` (the directory `/etc/gnome-vfs-2.0` does not exist in standard installation of Ubuntu 20.04, so you have to create it first)
12. create a script `/opt/gthumb_old/gvfsd_wrapper` with the following contents (the file must be executable):

```
#!/bin/sh
GVFSD_DIR=`/usr/bin/dirname $0`
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${GVFSD_DIR} ${GVFSD_DIR}/gnome-vfs-daemon
```

13. copy the file `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/gnome-vfs-daemon.service` from Ubuntu 10.04 to the same directory on Ubuntu 20.04 (`/usr/share/dbus-1/services`), then **edit it** as follows. The original file has the following contents:

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.gnome.GnomeVFS.Daemon
Exec=/usr/lib/gnome-vfs-2.0/gnome-vfs-daemon
```

Change it to:

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.gnome.GnomeVFS.Daemon
Exec=/opt/gthumb_old/gvfsd_wrapper
```

14. Finally, create a script `/usr/local/bin/gthumb_old` to run the application:

```
#!/bin/sh
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/gthumb_old /opt/gthumb_old/gthumb
```

(you can also create a launcher in menu or GNOME panel referring to this script).

The application does not conflict with the existing gThumb 3.8.0 from Ubuntu 20.04 as it stores its configuration data in a different place. Both can be used independently, but there is one possible problem described below.

**Note** that the application crashes in an image directory that has a `.comments` subdirectory containing comments created by newer version of gThumb. So in case when the application crashes after entering some directory, you should delete the `.comments` subdir.

I also found a strange case with two particular image files (out of several thousand I have). The application crashed in a directory that contained **symlinks** to these two files that were in another directory (when I replaced the symlinks with copies of the files or hard links, there was no crash - it happened on those two files only). If you don't have any symlinks in your image dirs, this problem should not appear.

Final screenshot of the working application:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will break the operating system due to dependencies issues. Hence I suggest to:
Download Ubuntu 10.04 from [here](https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.04.0/). Install it in VM container and run the app in it.

Comment: You are wrong, as - as I already wrote - I was able to fulfill all dependencies and the application **does run** and **does not complain about any missing library**. It only fails on interaction with current GNOME backend. I am interested if this can be solved somehow.